# Python mocking shutils always passes

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a module with many utility functions, most of which exec system calls.  One example is a function that copies a file to a new directory and returns the path.  I am writing unit tests for my utility module and am using mock.  However, while trying to mock `shutil.copy2` my unit test always passes.

the utility function

```
import os
from shutil import copy2

def cp_and_return_path(src, dst):
    """copy a file to a destination and return the destination path."""
    if os.path.isfile(src):
        copy2(src, config.TMP_DIR)
    return dst
```

and the unit test: inside of the class `UtilsTest(unittest2.TestCase)`.

```
import mock
import unittest2

from lib import utils
...
@mock.patch('utils.os')
@mock.patch('utils.copy2')
def test_cp_and_return_path(self, mock_copy, mock_os):
    mock_os.path.isfile.return_value = False
    utils.cp_and_return_path('file1', 'test/here')
    self.assertFalse(mock_copy.called)
```

this test passes even when i set the `isfile.return_value` to `True`. I am new to mock so perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Why you use `unittest2`? You really need it? What python version you use?

Comment: I'm using 2.7.2.  No real reason why I use unittest2, it was part of a tutorial I was following.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Maybe you have more than one `utils` module in your system and by `@mock.patch('utils.copy2')` you are patching the wrong one. Try to use `@mock.patch('lib.utils.copy2')` and `@mock.patch('lib.utils.os')` instead. If it is ok tell me I'll post it as answer for the record.